# Submitting simple form using jQuery - Why wont this work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#myform {display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id="uploadbutton">Upload Images</button>
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST" action="http://www.########.com/post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" accept="image/*" onchange="FileSelected();" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#uploadbutton').click(function() {
    $('#imagefile').trigger('click');
});

function FileSelected() {
 document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get this to work in IE9 and older browsers, but the jQuery submit() function just isn't firing. Ultimately, I'm building a script that submits images without refreshing the page and the form is hidden. An intricate FileSelected() function submits fileimages through AJAX on modern browsers, although I need help getting an alternative to work on older browsers which do not support this AJAX/file submission.

Let's start off simple: Why isn't this tiny script above working on IE9?

Comment: You may need to wait until the document is fully loaded to add the jquery event.  try $(function(){...}) around your existing script code.

Comment: @Lee - I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you do not submit the form.

Instead of:

```
$('#imagefile').trigger('click');
```

you need to use:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#imagefile').on('change', function (e) {
    if (this.value != '') {
      alert('loaded');

      // uncomment for testing
      //$('#myform').submit();
    }
  });

  $('#uploadbutton').click(function () {
    $('#imagefile').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```css
#myform {
   display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="uploadbutton">Upload Images</button>
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST" action="http://www.########.com/post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" accept="image/*"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried what you suggested and this submits the form before a file is even selected. I'm hiding the ugly "File Browse" button and the $('#imagefile').trigger('click'); line is there to allow a nice looking "Upload Image" button to simulates clicking the hidden "File Browse" button. (In my production script the file input field is hidden by css).

Comment: Your method will submit the form before you get a chance to select an image with the browsers build-in behaviour.

Comment: I've updated my original code to hide the form elements completely just like in my production script.

Comment: @gaetanoM - Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the "loaded --> submit" popup, but the form itself does not submit when I uncomment "$('#myform').submit();". I'm not seeing an error in IE9 Developer Tools either. For some reason, no matter what I do, I can't get the form to submit like this through jQuery.

Comment: @gaetanoM - I'm currently using Windows Vista - IE9.

Comment: @gaetanoM - Unfortunately, it just doesn't work. I even put the script and style in the <head> of the document, cleared the browser cache - copied and pasted directly from your snippets, but the submit() just doesn't work.

Comment: @gaetanoM - I changed the protocol and it still does not work.

Comment: @gaetanoM - Unfortunately, I tried that as well with no progress. I also reset IE9 browser settings to default and it's still not working (the code does work in modern browsers like Chrome though with no errors).

Comment: I completely uninstalled and re-installed IE9 and it still does not work. It didn't work with default IE8 either and I have no clue why something so simple is not working.

Comment: @gaetanoM - I changed the jquery.min.js file to a new version: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js - now there is an "access denied" error popping up (jquery.min.js, line 4 character 4915). Any idea what this means?

Comment: @gaetanoM - I figured out the problem, apparently the upload <button> needs to be a <label> - some odd IE type issue. Once this was done, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will need an submit element `<input type="submit" class='hidden />` (Although you submit it by jQuery)
Also try `$('#myform').trigger('submit');`

Comment: These suggestions are some of the first things I thought of, but they don't work either.

Comment: Is there any Error?

Comment: I have IE9 developer tools open and there does not appear to be any errors.

Answer (score 0):

the FileSelected method is not triggering a jQuery submit, it is doing it on the form element object.

In IE9 you may need to reference the document.forms collection with

```
document.forms[0].submit()
// or simply use jquery
$("#myForm").submit();
```